# Differentiate between PDF and PDF Portfolio Java

Tags: javascript, java, pdf

I am trying to differentiate between PDF and PDF portfolio file uploads in a Java 7 project. Unfortunately, both of these have the same data type, '.pdf', so that makes it difficult to easily distinguish between the two.

I am receiving the multipart data from a Javascript FormData object via an AJAX post request, so a JavaScript solution would also be acceptable.

Due to limitations on the project, I am not able to download or use external libraries or plugins(outside of jQuery) in my solution.

Comment: I'm not adding this as an answer because it is exactly the wrong way to accomplish your goal but... open the PDF as though it were a text file and search for "/Collection". If you find it, it's a Portfolio. Most of the time, that particular string won't be encrypted or in binary. However, you are far better off using a PDF library tool that can examine the document catalog and determine if the PDF is a "Collection"... meaning a Portfolio.

Comment: Why would this be the wrong way? just from a resource utilization point of view? or are there security concerns? Or is it just that it would be better/faster using a library?

Comment: It's wrong because you can't count on that string remaining clear text in the PDF in the future. In fact, there's no good reason for it to be in clear text today; that's just how Acrobat does it... for now. Using a library will let you examine the PDF object by object and is the more proper and future-proof way to go. Think of it this way... I can drive a nail into the wall using the sole of my shoe... It works and I don't need to go into the garage to find my hammer. But no one would say that I was using the right tool.